# Phonegap Cordova Error on ios

Tags: android, ios, cordova

im building an app with Phonegap Cordova, the Android version works fine, but when i build the IOS version, the app runs but i got this error

**"the old format of this exec call has been removed (deprecated since 2.1) Change to:  cordova.exec(null, null, 'Service', 'Action', [arg1, arg2])"**

Cordova version 6.3.1

plugins installed:

cordova-plugin-android-support-v4 21.0.1 "Android Support v4"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.0.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.2.1 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 1.7.1 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-file 4.2.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.5.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-googleplus 4.0.8 "Google+"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.4.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.2.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.1.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist"
pushbots-cordova-plugin 1.3.6 "Pushbots"

Anyone have any idea what can be?

Comment: You are not using the newest plugins. Remove them all and then add them again from npm.

Comment: @Joerg thanks man, works perfectly, I just had to update Android SDK before build again with the new plugins.